# How to substitute correctly in python using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a python string:

```
s = 'filename               13.00 50850.8732503344475    37.11  abc'
```

In order to find the second string with format `nn.nn`, I know I can do:

```
re.findall(r'.*(\b\d+\.\d+)',s)[0]
```

which finds:

```
'37.11'
```

But I want to replace it with 99.99.

I tried:

```
re.sub(r'.*(\b\d+\.\d+)','99.99',s)
```

But that just yields:

```
'99.99  abc'
```

whereas I want:

```
'filename               13.00 50850.8732503344475    99.99  abc'
```

Clearly I don't yet understand how regex works. Could someone offer help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should capture what you need to keep and use the unambiguous replaement backreference in the replacement pattern:

```
s = re.sub(r'(.*)\b\d+\.\d+',r'\g<1>99.99', s)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BTs83S) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kxKFNq/1).

**Pattern details**

- `(.*)` - Group 1 (its value is referred to with `\g<1>` backreference from the replacement pattern): any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can replace last occurrence of simple pattern `(\d+\.\d+)`:

```
s = "filename               13.00 50850.8732503344475    37.11  abc"
*_, last = re.finditer(r"(\d+\.\d+)", s)
s = s[:last.start()] + "99.99" + s[last.end():]
```

It's a bit faster. Results of timeit benchmark([code](https://repl.it/repls/SardonicSpeedyUsers)):

```
re.finditer() -> 11.30306268
re.sub() -> 15.613837582000002
```